# How can I recover from losing my construction yards?

Tags: command-and-conquer-red-alert

Playing with friends, I built multiple bases across the map in a tactic aimed at constricting resources for everybody else on the map. My base defences were pretty solid on land, but then I got attacked from the water by a pretty large fleet of cruisers.

By the time I responded, I had lost all of my construction yards and a large quantity of other buildings including war factories. This seemed to leave me in the position where my only option was to storm their base with the units I had remaining and all the foot soldiers I could afford.

How can I recover from losing my construction yards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from taking an enemies version of the same with an **engineer**, or building an **MCV** which you couldn't do due to your lost war factories, **you can't**.

Answer (score 3):

in addition to the above there is also a chance that an MCV will spawn as a result of picking up a crate

I'm not sure what the percentage chance is though